# Sorting a Group by Numbers which is like 1.0, 1.2,..., 1.14...and so on in SSRS

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table having sequence number like 1.0,1.1,1.2,....1.13,1.14 and so on. 
I need to Sort the columns in the table based on this sequence number. 
The problem here is when i give sort it is giving me the following:

> 1.1  Data 
>   1.10 Data2 
>   1.11 Data3 
>   1.12 Data4 
>   1.2  Data5

which is wrong and i need like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3...1.10

Suggest me some idea to get it.
Earlier response is appreciable.
Thanks.
Pavithra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to extract the relevant numbers from the sequence string, cast these substrings to `int`, then sort by these extracted `int` values.

Say I have data like yours:

[image]

I have added two **Calculated Fields** to the Dataset:

[image]

`FirstGroup`:

```
=CInt(Left(Fields!MyValue.Value, InStr(Fields!MyValue.Value, ".") - 1))
```

`SecondGroup`:

```
=CInt(Mid(Fields!MyValue.Value
    , InStr(Fields!MyValue.Value, ".") + 1
    , InStr(Fields!MyValue.Value, " ") - (InStr(Fields!MyValue.Value, ".") + 1)))
```

You can see I'm just using the built in SSRS text functions.

Create a Table and sort by these values:

[image]

[image]

This works for your example; obviously you might need to tweak slightly for your larger Dataset.

Comment: will you please help me on this. when i used the way you said its throwing an error, Argument "length" must be greater than or equal to zero and my datas will be having 2.1, 2.2,3.1,.. 10.1.. series also. am struggling with this sort.

Comment: and also will you please tell what you are doing by using those functions? Thanks